# Adding line breaks and indents to XmlDocument

Tags: .net, line-breaks, xmldocument

What is the right way of adding line breaks and indents when building an **XmlDocument** to make its output (called by **xmlDocoment->DocumentElement->OuterXml**) look like this:

```
<QualifyingProperties Target="#SignatureElem_0" xmlns="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
    <SignedProperties Id="SignedPropertiesElem_0">
```

This is the way I build my XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument^ xmlDoc = gcnew XmlDocument();
xmlDoc->PreserveWhitespace = true;

XmlNode^ nQualifyingProperties = xmlDoc->CreateNode(XmlNodeType::Element, "QualifyingProperties", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
xmlDoc->AppendChild(nQualifyingProperties);
XmlNode^ nodAttribute = xmlDoc->CreateNode(XmlNodeType::Attribute, "Target", "");
nodAttribute->Value = SignatureId;
nQualifyingProperties->Attributes->SetNamedItem(nodAttribute)

XmlNode^ nSignedProperties = xmlDoc->CreateNode(XmlNodeType::Element, "SignedProperties", "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#");
nQualifyingProperties->AppendChild(nSignedProperties);
nodAttribute = xmlDoc->CreateNode(XmlNodeType::Attribute, "Id", "");
nodAttribute->Value = SignedPropertiesId;
nSignedProperties->Attributes->SetNamedItem(nodAttribute);
```

I found that this works for line breaks:

```
XmlNode^ linebreak = xmlDoc->CreateTextNode("\n");
nQualifyingProperties->AppendChild(linebreak );
```

But I'm not sure it's the right way. Is it? And what about indents (tabs)?

*EDIT*:
I am adding this XmlDocument to SignedXml as DataObject (where it's going to be signed), therefore I can't control formatting of this particular element, and while it's not a big deal, it would be nice to make it work the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. *XmlDocument* should be written to a *Stream* with *XmlWriter* using, like Pavel suggested, *XmlWriterSettings* with *Indent* property enabled. Like this:

```
XmlDocument^ xmlDocument = gcnew XmlDocument();
xmlDocument->PreserveWhitespace = true;

//add some elements

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
XmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
XmlWriterSettings.IndentChars = "\t"; //tabs instead of spaces

Stream^ stream = gcnew MemoryStream(); //or FileStream to write an Xml file directly to disk

XmlWriter^ writer = XmlWriter::Create(stream, settings);
xmlDocument->WriteTo(writer);
writer->Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XmlWriter` with `StringBuilder` backing store and `XmlWriterSettings` with `Indent` property enabled. E.g.

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
// generate document here

var buffer = new StringBuilder();
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(buffer, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true });
document.Save(writer);
writer.Close();

Console.WriteLine(buffer);
```

There should not be an issue to convert it from C# to C++ managed extensions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the OuterXml property, and it'd be a bad idea to try to insert formatting characters into the document itself, but there are a few other ways.

The most direct way to get what you want with the XmlDocument API is to use the XmlDocument.Save() method - you could try XmlDocument->Save(Stream) to save it to a MemoryStream and then read the stream.  That would give you a pretty printed version.

It'd be easier if you could use an XDocument, but apparently that's not supported in C++.  If you have the option of including some managed code in your project, it would look like this:

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
return xd.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. XmlDocument.Save() does the job, but from what I remember, it uses spaces for indentation instead of conventionally used tabs.